# phpstorm doesn't give suggestion

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have two classes A and B and A class has property of B class object. When I try to call this B class function phpstorm does not show any suggestion. I'm doing like this

```
Class A {
    public $b;
    function __construct($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function  someWork() {
        $this->b->anotherWork();
    }
}

Class B {
    public function callA() {
        $a = new A($this);
        $a->someWork();
    }
    public function anotherWork() {
        echo "do somethings";
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->callA();
```

when typing  $this->b->anotherWork() phpstorm does not show any suggestion. Is there any way to get suggestion of all class B function from this b variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use type hinting.

In class A declare your constructor like this:

```
public function _construct(B $b) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This also allows PHP to type check the argument at runtime and report an error if it is wrong.

Comment: Wow this looks more clear and understandable. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try type hinting on the variable and/or PHPDoc on the function and it should work great.

```
Class A {
    /** @var B */
    public $b;

    /**
     * @param B $b
     */
    function __construct($b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function  someWork() {
        $this->b->anotherWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, in this case I think your just looking for the type hint on the property `b` of class `A`, but using PHPDoc is never a bad idea.

Comment: Ya I have upvoted your answer But I think I should accept @Hobo Sapiens's answer.